# jQuery CSS3, the second 'rotate()' in 'transform: rotate() translate() rotate()' , replaces the first one

Tags: jquery, html, css, transform

I have this part of code that aligns divs around a circle:

```
angle = 0; mangle = 0;        
for(i = 1; i<= count; i++)
{
    $("#p" +i).css("transform", "rotate(" + angle + "deg) translate(250px) rotate("+mangle+"deg)");
    angle = 360 / count;
    mangle = (-1) * angle;
}
```

but the problem is that the second rotate() replaces the first one at last!
for example it should be:

```
rotate(30deg) translate(250px) rotate(-30deg)
```

but it gives:

```
rotate(-30deg) translate(250px)
```

I even tried http://ricostacruz.com/jquery.transit but it didn't help. so what's the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although I didn't find any solutions for this, but I did a trick!
I have div elements with ids '#p1' , '#p2', ...
so I created another div inside each one then applied the second 'rotate()' to this new div and it worked :)

It was:

```
<div id='p1'> content </div>
<div id='p2'> content </div>
<div id='p3'> content </div>
```

jQuery:

```
angle = 0; mangle = 0;        
for(i = 1; i<= count; i++)
{
    $("#p" +i).css("transform", "rotate(" + angle + "deg) translate(250px) rotate("+mangle+"deg)");
    angle = 360 / count;
    mangle = (-1) * angle;
}
```

now It is:

```
<div id='p1'><div> content </div></div>
<div id='p2'><div> content </div></div>
<div id='p3'><div> content </div></div>
```

jQuery:

```
angle = 0; mangle = 0;        
for(i = 1; i<= count; i++)
{
    $("#p" +i).css("transform", "rotate(" + angle + "deg) translate(250px)");
    $("#p" +i).children('div').css("transform", "rotate(" + mangle + "deg)");
    angle = 360 / count;
    mangle = (-1) * angle;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to put the second "rotate" in a second "transform". It's my first idea.

Comment: thanks for your recommendation, but the problem is that the second transform will totally replace the first, so only the second transform will work.